# Do you need to run as admin to do Netsh port forwarding using cmd?

Tags: command-prompt, netsh

Simple question I need to know if Netsh port forwarding works without the command prompt running as administrator.
Meaning that I will be running the classic command prompt.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this **netsh command** in my cmd with and without admin rights and here is the result:

[image: classic cmd vs admin cmd]

As you can see, in both case results turned out to be same and tried
**netsh wlan name="" key=clear** too, and the results was same, so my conclusion is you'll need not to run your cmd as admin **unless you want to make some changes in the computer** like, installing/uninstalling directories or programs etc..,

Comment: So then port forwarding using netsh wouldnt be a problem on classic cmd?
Also thanks for taking your time helping out!

Comment: Yes , but in case of this networking, it is recommended to always run cmd as admin for port forwarding, since it acquires many info about your system, your classic cmd might block some data transmitted, therefore try with Admin cmd for port forwarding

Comment: 1 question, the data transmitted through the ports will not be affected or blocked right? 
But only some visual data shown in cmd?

Comment: well, you have a point, but we don't know what exactly happens at the backend either, just try using Admin cmd, this is what I've found from my own research, don't stop your own research until it satisfies you.